# How to get which specific attribute of model has been changed? Is this possible in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So for example, I have a model with attributes: firstName, lastName, age, skills, race, birthdate, and about 20 more...

I want to get `which specific attributes were changed` (if user changes some) and do a `.save()` placing the specific attributes that were changed as arguments for `.save({...})`

Any way I can do this?

*note: backbone.js newbie*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the fine backbone documentation, http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-change
in particular `hasChanged`, and `changedAttributes`